# Chat bot framework 401 unauthorized issue

Tags: bots

I'm getting 401 issue when i deployed the bot in local iis and registered the bot channel in azure with ngrok https url.

Steps i followed :

1. Deployed bot in IIS with port 1214.
2. created https using ngrok for the port 1214
   [image: ngrok screenshot]
3. Registered channel in Azure portal and given end point as ngrok url.
   [image: Azure portal Channel registration]
4. i try accessing the WEB chat using the iframe url in the browser & getting 401 error. I verified the MS appid & password in both web.config in my local server and azure portal,both are same.
   [image: iframe webchat snapshot]
5. I have tried accessing the iis bot server using the emulator with ngrok ulr and given empty ms appid & password and changed web.config to empty appid,password, it's working fine.
   [image: Emulator]

Please help.

**Edited :**

I have debugged the botconnector(github) source code and figured out the issue,but not sure how to fix it.

[Token expire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRnzo.png)
Token expires in short time even for first time chat but the time difference in the screen shot shows too long (validto and current). so what may be the issue ? As i said my bot is running in my local server (location india) and i registered bot channel with endpoint as ngrok url running in my local server. (pls refer details above.).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. Its due to wrong time zone settings in my system.

Comment: Hello, can you please explain what exact issue have you been facing with timezone? and how you changed your local timezone so it started working?

Comment: I am getting the exact same error, but the answer provided is not clear

Answer (score 1):

Try [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems#issue-an-http-request-to-the-microsoft-login-service) your bot.

If you don't get a success response reset your app password.

Comment: i have edited my question with new findings, but not able to fix it.

Comment: @Velmurugan - Using ngrok wouldn't be an issue. If you have given your AppId and AppPassword in the web.config file how can the bot respond if you don't provide the values in emulator? :/

Comment: my web.config is empty appid and password during my testing. it works. Issue is with token expires.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error "**Error: Unauthorized. Invalid AppId passed on token**" while trying to access a bot deployed in Azure from the bot emulator. The solution was to go to Bot registration>Access control> I added myself as the owner of the bot. And it started working for me in the emulator. I gave http://localhost:port and didnt provide the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword in the emulator and I was able to debug the bot locally.